# How to add hidden ocr Text in PDF

Tags: pdf, ocr, tiff

Currently I am working on Puma.NET and converted scanned multi-paged tif into searchable pdf file. However, is there any open source library that provide functionality to produce image over this text pdf? This way original tif file is preserved in pdf format and the ocr text is hidden but available for selection or searching.

---

Thanks Andrew for quick response. If my existing library won't work to achieve the result I will surely give QuickPDF a shot. :-)

Btw, I just got a better idea. I think I can do it using iTextSharp. However, I have 2 questions as I an newbie for iTextSharp.

1) How to add pages with different size in pdf? 
2) How to add image layer on specific page using SetAbsolutePosition or any other function?

If any one can provide me iTextSharp code for above questions, it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Quick PDF Library LITE which should have enough functions to do what you need.  It is not open source but is free to use.

http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/free/lite.php

You would need to use the following functions

QP.SetPageSize();
  QP.SetOrigin();
  QP.AddImageFromFile();
  QP.SetTextSize();
  QP.DrawTextBox();
  QP.SetTextColor();
  QP.NewPage();

You would need to add white text objects before adding the image.

Andrew.

Disclaimer : I do some consulting work for this product.

Comment: I have successfully added image layer in my OCR'd pdf text formatting and positions are not preserved. Is is possible with Quick PDF LITE version?

Comment: If you have the coordinates of each piece of OCR data then you can use DrawTextBox(x,y,w,h, text, alignment) to place invisible text pretty accurately.

Which OCR engine are you using ?  If you are using Tesseract 2.xx then it is most likely you don't have access to the x,y,w,h positions of the OCR text.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have co-ordinates. I think i would keep this question open for sometime as it seems that there is no free solution available right now.